# Why I get the same image after drawing a line with cv2.line?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, google-colaboratory

I use Python and OpenCv in Google Colaboratory and apparently I cant draw a line on an image. Anything wrong with the code below? Image remains unchanged

```
cv2_imshow(vdisp)
hough_vdisp = cv2.line(vdisp, (0, 20), (50, 100), (0,255,0), 5, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2_imshow(hough_vdisp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. My image was grayscale and I was using a RGB color instead of a value from 0 to 255.